# How can i run this query for each user without using any function or procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, gaps-and-islands

Here is my query which returns streaks for specific user=27:

```
SELECT MAX(sum) AS streak
FROM (
  SELECT
    game_date,
    IF(points > 0, @sum:=@sum+1, @sum:=0) AS sum
  FROM (
    SELECT
      game_date,
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM point WHERE user_id = 27 AND bet_id = b.id AND goals > 0) AS points
    FROM bet b
    WHERE game_date < NOW()
    ORDER BY game_date DESC
  ) t1, (SELECT @sum:=0) t2
) t;
```

**What i try:** it runs successfully on my local MySQL but gives an error on live phpMyAdmin that user_id is an unknown column in the where clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id,(
SELECT MAX(SUM) AS streak
FROM (
  SELECT
    game_date,
    IF(points > 0, @sum:=@sum+1, @sum:=0) AS SUM
  FROM (
    SELECT
      game_date,
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM POINT WHERE user_id = p.user_id AND bet_id = b.id AND goals > 0) AS points
    FROM bet b
    WHERE game_date < NOW()
    ORDER BY game_date DESC
  ) t1, (SELECT @sum:=0) t2
) t) AS streak FROM POINT p;
```

Comment: `p.user_id` does not exist in the scope of that innermost correlated sub-query. Please would you update your question with the DDL for the relevant tables, along with some sample data. Will `points` (the correlated sub-query) always be either 0 or 1, or can there be multiple `point` rows for a given (user_id, bet_id)? What version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: Yes i have to count as 0 or 1 always in order to find consecutive max bet count.

Comment: MySql version is 8.1.14

Comment: The latest GA release is MySQL 8.0.32. Try running `SELECT VERSION();`. I have made a change to the way the `@sum` is reset when moving from one user to another in the result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any sample data to test against, I may be way off the mark but give this a try:

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(SUM) AS streak
FROM (
    SELECT b.game_date, u.user_id,
        IF(
            IFNULL(p.bet_id, 0) > 0,
            IF(@prev_user = u.user_id, @sum := @sum + 1, @sum := 1),
            @sum := 0
        ) AS SUM,
        @prev_user := u.user_id
    FROM bet b
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM `POINT`) u
    LEFT JOIN `POINT` p ON b.id = p.bet_id AND u.user_id = p.user_id AND p.goals > 0
    JOIN (SELECT @sum:=0, @prev_user:=0) vars
    WHERE b.game_date < NOW()
    ORDER BY u.user_id ASC, b.game_date DESC
) t
GROUP BY user_id;
```

This is a variation of the [gaps-and-islands](https://towardsdatascience.com/gaps-and-islands-with-mysql-b407040d133d) problem.This query takes a different (*"modern"*) approach, using the [ROW_NUMBER()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) [window function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) -

```
SELECT user_id, IFNULL(MAX(streak), 0)
FROM (
    SELECT *, rn1 - rn2,
        IF (
            goals IS NOT NULL,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, rn1 - rn2 ORDER BY game_date),
            NULL
        ) AS streak
    FROM (
        SELECT b.id AS bet_id, b.game_date, u.user_id, p.goals,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY u.user_id, game_date) rn1,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY u.user_id, IF(p.bet_id IS NULL, 0, 1) ORDER BY game_date) rn2
        FROM bet b
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM `POINT`) u
        LEFT JOIN `POINT` p ON b.id = p.bet_id AND u.user_id = p.user_id AND p.goals > 0
        WHERE b.game_date < NOW()
    ) t1
) t2
GROUP BY user_id;
```